# Injecting a dependency to constructor of an attribute in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, c#-8.0, dsharp+

I have the following attribute:

```
public class MultipleInteractivitiesAttribute : CheckBaseAttribute
{
    private readonly IInteractivityService _interactivityService;

    public MultipleInteractivitiesAttribute(IInteractivityService interactivityService)
    {
        _interactivityService = interactivityService;
    }

    public override Task<bool> ExecuteCheckAsync(CommandContext ctx, bool help)
    {
        var userId = ctx.User.Id;
        var cmdName = ctx.Command.QualifiedName;

        return Task.FromResult(!_interactivityService.CheckForUserInteractivity(userId, cmdName));
    }
}
```

And the following class which has a method I use the attribute on.

```
public class RecruitmentModule : BaseCommandModule
{
    private readonly IInteractivityService _interactivityService;

    public RecruitmentModule(IInteractivityService interactivityService)
    {
        _interactivityService = interactivityService;
    }
    
    [Command("apply"), MultipleInteractivities()]
    public async Task Apply(CommandContext ctx)
    {
          // some code here
    }
}
```

Now I get a problem when I use the `MultipleInteractivities` as attribute above the `Apply` method. It expects me to pass an argument to its constructor.

Now since I already inject `IInteractivityService` in the constructor of the `RecruitmentModule` class. I try to pass it as an argument to my `MultipleInteractivities` attribute.

Like this:

`[Command("apply"), MultipleInteractivities(_interactivityService)]`

However, this gives the following error:

> Cannot access non-static field '_interactivityService' in static context

So I try to make `_interactivityService` field static in the `RecruitmentModule` class like this:

`private static IInteractivityService _interactivityService;`

Now I get the following error when it is passed as an argument to my `MultipleInteractivities` attributes.

> Attribute constructor parameter 'interactivityService' has type 'DiscordBot.Core.Interfaces.IInteractivityService', which is not a valid attribute parameter type

How can I get `IInteractivityService` passed to my `MultipleInteractivitiesAttribute` without getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to ([and shouldn't](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2014/dependency-injection-in-attributes-dont-do-it/)) inject the dependency into the attribute constructor. Instead, the `CommandContext` has a [`Services`](https://dsharpplus.github.io/api/DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.CommandContext.html#DSharpPlus_CommandsNext_CommandContext_Services) property returning an `IServiceProvider` that you can use to resolve the dependency:

```
public class MultipleInteractivitiesAttribute : CheckBaseAttribute 
{ 
    public override Task<bool> ExecuteCheckAsync(CommandContext ctx, bool help) 
    { 
        var userId = ctx.User.Id; 
        var cmdName = ctx.Command.QualifiedName; 
        var interactivityService = ctx.Services.GetService<IInteractivityService>();

        return Task.FromResult(!interactivityService.CheckForUserInteractivity(userId, cmdName)); 
    } 
}
```